# gcloud logging write size limited to 128 kb

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-stackdriver, logentries, gcp-stackdriver

In GCP, I'm trying to add a Stackdriver log entry of size 138 kb as a json payload using a cloud shell command. It failed, saying "arguments are too long" . I'm able to insert entries of size less than or equal to 128 kb. As per the documentation , it says it can allow upto 256 kb.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas

`gcloud logging write --payload-type=json my-test-log "{\"message\": \"My message\", \"weather\": \"aaaaa\.................."}"`

Comment: I think the error is coming from the operating system shell (sh, bash, etc) and not from the program itself. I do not know the maximum size of the log entry field `jsonPayload` but it is not 256 KB. The CLI `gcloud` is just Python code that is installed on your system. Review the source code to determine the limits imposed by the program. Per the documentation, ***gcloud logging write should be used for simple testing purposes***.